# PHP Parse error parse error with Swift mailer SmtpTransport

Tags: php, heroku

For testing sake, I want to send an email from my Heroku server with a hardcoded message. When I call the page "sendMessage.php," I get a 500 error on Heroku. To investigate the 500 error, I bring the code down the MAMP to investigate the log errors. When I do that, I get the following syntactical error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$transport' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sendmail.php on line 6
```

Here's what my code looks like. I downloaded the latest version of swift mailer from github. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php 

 require 'SwiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php'


$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')
            ->setUserName('FOO@gmail.com')
            ->setPassword('BAR');


$swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($transport)


$content = "This is a test message.";



$message = Swift_Message::newInstance("This is a test email")
            ->setFrom("FOO@gmail.com")
            ->setTo('BAR@gmail.com')
            ->setBody($content,'text/html')
            ->addPart(strip_tags($content),'text/plain');



$swift->send($message);


?>
```

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of your `require` line

Comment: You're also missing a `;` at the end of `$swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($transport)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semi colon `;` in two lines.
Here is correction.

```
require 'SwiftMailer/lib/swift_required.php'; // missing ; here

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')
            ->setUserName('FOO@gmail.com')
            ->setPassword('BAR');
$swift = Swift_Message::newInstance($transport); // missing ; here

$content = "This is a test message.";

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance("This is a test email")
            ->setFrom("FOO@gmail.com")
            ->setTo('BAR@gmail.com')
            ->setBody($content,'text/html')
            ->addPart(strip_tags($content),'text/plain');

$swift->send($message);
```